# ArcGIS Pro and PiP installs

Tags: arcgis-pro, pip

I need to install selenium to automate an ArcGIS Online workflow. I have Python 3x installed with pro in this path:

```
C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python
```

These are the subdirectories:

```
08/03/2020  09:38 PM    <DIR>          .
08/03/2020  09:38 PM    <DIR>          ..
06/09/2020  02:28 PM                35 .condarc
11/12/2019  11:33 AM                 0 .nonadmin
08/03/2020  09:38 PM    <DIR>          conda-meta
11/12/2019  11:34 AM         6,973,824 cwp.exe
08/03/2020  09:38 PM    <DIR>          DLLs
08/03/2020  09:37 PM    <DIR>          envs
08/03/2020  09:38 PM    <DIR>          Lib
08/03/2020  09:38 PM    <DIR>          pkg-metadata
08/03/2020  09:38 PM    <DIR>          pkgs
08/03/2020  09:38 PM    <DIR>          res
08/03/2020  09:38 PM    <DIR>          Scripts
```

I've tried setting environmental variables, running `setx PATH “%PATH%;C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\Scripts”`

And I continue to get an error (pip is not recognized as an internal or external command" when trying to install selenium using pip.

What do I need to do to make pip installs work? Also, is there a place I need to have the selenium and related java sdk files installed to make the pip install work so I can run selenium commands in Python?

Comment: @ user2856 OMG! Thank you so much. That was so much easier than the way I was going about it. Cloned environment and went to add package and selemium was already there. Please post answer and I will check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the path of your **root** Pro conda environment, it is only used for managing conda environments, there's not even an [actual python executable in there, just the conda executable](https://community.esri.com/thread/249399-when-is-pro-leaving-2017-behind-conda).

Your **actual** Pro python directory is `C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3`.

However, this environment is **read-only**, you cannot install anything in it. To have a writeable environment, you need to make a clone using the ArcGIS Pro Package Manager.

For more information see - https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/get-started/what-is-conda.htm